# LocalStack - CloudFormation Returns Error Code: 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm currently want to simulate AWS environment using **LocalStack**. But upon creating-stacks, the service returned me a error code: 500.

Here's my template file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'Sample'
Resources:
  sample:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
      Properties:
        MemorySize: 256
        Timeout: 10
        Runtime: nodejs8.10
        Handler: /dist/service/src/handler.sample
        Code:
          Zipfile: lambda.zip
```

Here's the command i'm trying to run:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
  --template-body file://localstack/cloudtemplate.yaml \
  --stack-name sample \
  --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4581 \
```

And here's the output:

```
Unable to parse response (syntax error: line 1, column 54), invalid XML received:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

It seems that the cloudformation endpoint of the localstack doesn't work properly. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The error you get back from `LocalStack` is quite vague so you need to dig in a bit deeper. First of all can you post how you start `LocalStack` (is it through Docker and if so what is the exact command line)?

Using Docker and docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:

  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    ports:
      - "4567-4584:4567-4584"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=cloudformation
      - HOSTNAME=localstack
      - DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-2
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - DEBUG=1
```

A few things to note here:

- `DEBUG=1` will give you the exact error in the console you execute the docker-compose from which may (or may not) help you diagnose the actual issue
- You need to make sure that `Cloudformation` is started (by adding it in the `SERVICES` array) and that the appropriate port is opened. The default is 4581 (I am just using the default setup above opening all the ports `LocalStack` uses)
- `:latest` is used. I had an older version of the image and had issues with `Cloudformation` which went away by upgrading to latest. Not sure at which point this was fixed but I guess it does not matter.

And to ensure that the issue is not with your template try using one that works, e.g. pick one from here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html

Using the **SQS Queue with Cloudwatch Alarms** YAML example the following command works for me:

`aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name myteststack --template-body file://cloudf.yml --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4581`

If the above works and you still have issues with your template then at least you know where the issue lies (and maybe you can post the more detailed DEBUG output).